# Add UIViewcontroller with xib with UITableView in UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I'm trying to add a `UIViewController` in a `UIScrollView`, the `UIViewController` have a `UITableView` added with Interface Builder, i have connected it to data source and delegate to the File Owner's then i have connect the `IBOutlet` property with the `ActivityView` class, when i have do this to add to the `UIScrollView`:

```
ActivityView *viewActivity = [[ActivityView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ActivityView" bundle:nil];
[self.scrollView addSubview:viewActivity.view];
```

but when i open the view the app crash sometime with a `BAD_EXC_ACCESS`, sometime with a `SIGBRT` with this error:

```
[UILabel tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd27f8d0
```

and sometime is this:

```
[SMPageControl tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd68dcb0
```

and sometime is this:

```
[NSPathStore2 tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd3746b0
```

i can't understand how ti fix it, if i use the ActivityView alone, without adding it to the `UIScrollview`, works perfectly, and if i add ActivityView without the connection with the UITableView works, so i think the problem is adding it to the `UIScrollView` with the UITableView outlet connection, how i can do it?

this is the code of ActivityView:

```
#import "ActivityView.h"

@interface ActivityView () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *activities;

@end

@implementation ActivityView

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.activities count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.activities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.activities = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self.activities addObject:@"row"];
}
```

EDIT: i have tried also to add the UITableView programmatically, without interface builder, and when i set the datasource delegate, crash...everyone can try...crash always...

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I am going to speculate that this issue is that UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView.  Not sure how that borks the responder chain, though.

Comment: No i haven't solve the problem

Comment: Any luck with this? I have exactly the same issue. Table inside ViewController inside ScrollView.